# Make axis ticks strings in d3

Tags: d3.js

I am updating a d3 graph written by the previous developer. As non-expert ind d3 I am finding it quite hard to find answers to my problems. One thing i want to do is to change the x-axis ticks to pick up string values from state, however, everything I try ruins the chart.

The data:

```
let extractedData = [
  { label: '2018-7-3', wage: 7.5 },
  { label: '2018-5-3', wage: 6.1 },
  { label: '2018-1-3', wage: 5.3 },
  { label: '2018-11-3', wage: 6.1 }
];
```

Labels should become x-axis ticks.

```
    const x_scale = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 4])
      .range([padding, chart_width - 3 * padding]);

    const x_axis = d3
      .axisBottom(x_scale)
      .ticks(4)
      .tickSize(1)
```

The entire block of code for building this chart is:

```
const x_scale = d3
          .scaleLinear()
          .domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.label; }))
          .range([padding, chart_width - 3 * padding]);

        const y_scale = d3
          .scaleLinear()
          .domain([0, wages])
          .range([chart_height - 2 * padding, padding]);

        const svg = d3
          .select('#lineChart')
          .append('svg')
          .attr('width', chart_width)
          .attr('height', chart_height)
          .attr('viewBox', '0 0 700 700');
        //create axes
        const x_axis = d3
          .axisBottom(x_scale)
          .ticks(4)
          .tickSize(0)
          .tickFormat(function (d) {
            return d;
          });

        const y_axis = d3
          .axisLeft(y_scale)
          .ticks(10)
          .tickSize(0)
          .tickFormat(function (d) {
            return '£' + d;
          });
        //draw axes
        svg
          .append('g')
          .attr('class', 'xAxis')
          .attr(
            'transform',
            'translate(' + padding + ', ' + (chart_height - 2 * padding) + ')'
          )
          .call(x_axis);
        svg
          .append('g')
          .attr('class', 'yAxis')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(' + 2 * padding + ',0)')
          .call(y_axis);

        svg
          .select('.xAxis')
          .selectAll('text')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(0,10)')
          .attr('font-size', '1.5rem');

        svg
          .select('.yAxis')
          .selectAll('text')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(-10,0)')
          .attr('font-size', '1.5rem');
        //create circles
        svg
          .selectAll('circle') // selecting the cicles that dont yet exist. sending the data to the waiting room to wait for circles to be created
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append('circle')
          .attr('cx', function (d) {
            return x_scale(d.label); // d3 can work out which number to use on the axis to plot correctly
          })
          .attr('cy', function (d) {
            return y_scale(d.wage);
          })
          .attr('r', 10)
          .attr('fill', '#FFD254');

        //create labels for circles
        svg
          .append('g') // first create, append and select a group
          .selectAll('text') // then when you do 'select all text' you know that no text exists in this group because it has just been created
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append('text')
          .text(function (d) {
            return '£' + d.wage;
          })
          .attr('x', function (d) {
            return x_scale(d.label) + padding / 3;
          })
          .attr('y', function (d) {
            return y_scale(d.wage);
          })
          .attr('font-size', '1.5rem');
        //create horizontal line
        svg
          .append('line')
          .attr('x1', padding * 2)
          .attr('x2', chart_width - 2 * padding)
          .attr('y1', y_scale(min_wage))
          .attr('y2', y_scale(min_wage))
          .style('stroke', 'red')
          .style('stroke-width', '2px');
        svg
          .append('text')
          .attr(
            'transform',
            'translate(' +
            (chart_width - 2 * padding) +
            ' ,' +
            (chart_height - padding / 2) +
            ')'
          )
          .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
          .style('font-size', '1.5rem')
          .text('Month');
      })
  };
```

Comment: Do you want a linear Time scale or an Ordinal scale? If you want to show the ticks in this order it would be pretty strange because the dates are not sorted.

Comment: I was hoping it would be possible not to use Time scale as the dates will be random, not necessarily in chronological order. I was hoping to keep the order of dates as they are in the data object. I was also hoping I could just format ticks as strings and not even change the d3 code. Thank you so much for trying to answer

Comment: What type of graph are you plotting? Do you want a line graph with an Ordinal Scale on the X-axis? What is the argument for your `x_scale()` function? Without the full stripped down code it is a guessing/question game.

Comment: Side note - having the `padding` in the scale range is **bad** practice

Comment: I will update the quetsion @rioV8 and include all of the code. Solving this issue would help me so much! Our d3 person moved on to another project. We are building a scatter graph.

Comment: @rioV8 thank you so much for trying to help. I hope I renamed all this.state.data into data. padding is a variable name, not actually padding. Hopefully it makes it better practice.

Comment: Use the following example: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304 Replace the drawing of rects with your circles at `x_scale(d.label)+x_scale.bandwidth()*0.5` then you also get rid of this ugly padding variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Using margins is always a good practice

   ```
   margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 70},
   ```
2. Based on these margins, I'm creating a group for all the elements

   ```
   var g = svg.append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
   ```
3. **Most important requirement in your question: Strings as axis ticks**

   As @rioV8 mentions in the comments as well, it's better you use an ordinal scale.

   ```
   const x_scale = d3
     .scaleBand()
     .domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.label; }))
     .rangeRound([0, chart_width]).padding(0.1);
   ```
4. Setting the `yScale` domain to the extent of the **wages** and using [d3 nice](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#continuous_nice) to round off the values:

   ```
   const y_scale = d3
     .scaleLinear()
     .domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return +d.wage; })).nice()
     .rangeRound([chart_height, 0]);
   ```
5. Moving all circles/texts to within groups

   ```
   var circlesGroup = g.append('g').classed('circles', true);
   //create circles
   circlesGroup.selectAll('circle') ....
   ```
6. Changed 'text-anchor` to the X axis text (Month) to 'end' to align it

   ```
   .style('text-anchor', 'end')
   ```
7. You didn't have a `min_wage` set - so I've set it to 7

Putting together all of the above, here's a code snippet:

```js
var width = 900,
 height = 550,
  padding = 0,
  margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 70},
  min_wage = 7;
  
  var chart_height = height-margin.top-margin.bottom,
   chart_width = width-margin.left-margin.right;

let data = [
  { label: '2018-7-3', wage: 7.5 },
  { label: '2018-5-3', wage: 6.1 },
  { label: '2018-1-3', wage: 5.3 },
  { label: '2018-11-3', wage: 6.1 }
];

const x_scale = d3.scaleBand()
          .domain(data.map(function (d) { return d.label; }))
          .rangeRound([0, chart_width]).padding(0.1);

        const y_scale = d3
          .scaleLinear()
          .domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return +d.wage; })).nice()
          .rangeRound([chart_height, 0]);

        const svg = d3
          .select('#lineChart')
          .append('svg')
          .attr('width', width)
          .attr('height', height);
          
   var g = svg.append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");          
        //create axes
        const x_axis = d3
          .axisBottom(x_scale)
          .ticks(4)
          .tickFormat(function (d) {
            return d;
          });

        const y_axis = d3
          .axisLeft(y_scale)
          .ticks(10)
          .tickSize(0)
          .tickFormat(function (d) {
            return '£' + d;
          });
        //draw axes
        g
          .append('g')
          .attr('class', 'xAxis')
          .attr(
            'transform',
            'translate(0, ' + (chart_height) + ')'
          )
          .call(x_axis);
        g
          .append('g')
          .attr('class', 'yAxis')
          .call(y_axis);

        g
          .select('.xAxis')
          .selectAll('text')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(0,10)')
          .attr('font-size', '1.5rem');

        g
          .select('.yAxis')
          .selectAll('text')
          .attr('transform', 'translate(-10,0)')
          .attr('font-size', '1.5rem');
          
        var circlesGroup = g.append('g').classed('circles', true);
        //create circles
        circlesGroup
          .selectAll('circle') // selecting the cicles that dont yet exist. sending the data to the waiting room to wait for circles to be created
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append('circle')
          .attr('cx', function (d) {
            return x_scale(d.label)+x_scale.bandwidth()/2; // d3 can work out which number to use on the axis to plot correctly
          })
          .attr('cy', function (d) {
            return y_scale(d.wage);
          })
          .attr('r', 10)
          .attr('fill', '#FFD254');

    var textsGroup = g.append('g').classed('texts', true);
        //create labels for circles
        textsGroup
          .append('g') // first create, append and select a group
          .selectAll('text') // then when you do 'select all text' you know that no text exists in this group because it has just been created
          .data(data)
          .enter()
          .append('text')
          .text(function (d) {
            return '£' + d.wage;
          })
          .attr('x', function (d) {
            return x_scale(d.label) + x_scale.bandwidth()/2;
          })
          .attr('y', function (d) {
            return y_scale(d.wage);
          })
          .attr('font-size', '1.5rem');
        //create horizontal line
        g
          .append('line')
          .attr('x1', 0)
          .attr('x2', chart_width)
          .attr('y1', y_scale(min_wage))
          .attr('y2', y_scale(min_wage))
          .style('stroke', 'red')
          .style('stroke-width', '2px');
        g
          .append('text')
          .attr(
            'transform',
            'translate(' +
            (chart_width - 2 * padding) +
            ' ,' +
            (chart_height - padding / 2) +
            ')'
          )
          .style('text-anchor', 'end')
          .style('font-size', '1.5rem')
          .text('Month');
```

```css
text {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<div id="lineChart">

</div>
```

**EDIT:**
Changed the positioning of the circles and the labels using the scale bandwidth:

```
      .attr('x', function (d) {
        return x_scale(d.label) + x_scale.bandwidth()/2;
      })
```

(changed the tickSize to 6 to make sure the above edit works)

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is awesome! I may have destroyed an even larger part of my chart by now by rebuilding it as .scaleTime(). Something was actually happening. But I guess scaleBand() makes more sense.

Comment: I am really tempted to ask a couple more questions @Shashank. Can I?

Comment: Sure. If it's a new requirement, I'd suggest you to create a new question. If it's something related to my answer, sure please do. I'd be happy to help anyway.

Comment: Related to answer somewhat @Shashank. Also when I used scaleTime() I had the same problem The yellow dots are meant to align to ticks on x-axis but they do not. How can they be aligned?

Comment: Thank you for your help @Shashank. To sum up key point: I needed scaleBand() tip mostly. But I got much more than that.

Comment: I wonder if I can ask another question and tag your name in a comment to it @Shashank

Comment: Edited the post that has the circles/texts positioned based on the X-axis. Glad I could help. :) And for the new question, I'm not sure if I'll get a notification but I'll keep a look out for new questions. Will be happy to help.